# mex Error: command not found

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to run a simple mex example in matlab.  The .c program is

```
#include <math.h>
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    printf("Hello World!\n");
}
```

When I try the command "mex helloWorld.c" I get the following error message:

```
/home/rory/com/machine: Command not found.

Warning: You are using gcc version "4.7.2-2)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.4.x".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/
```

I understand the second error message.  But I have no idea what the first means.  Rory is not my name (I am on a work pc).  What specific command is being sought after and where can I find the option to change to a more appropriate path?

Thanks,
Thomas

[update] - I have replaced printf with mexPrintf, as suggested.  The error remains, but it seems to compile and run correctly.  Running -setup produces the same error, but otherwise informs me of the options file currently in use as it normally does.

At the moment, it looks like I can ignore the error.

Thanks again.

Comment: It likely isn't cause of your error, but you should use [`mexPrintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexprintf.html) instead of `printf` in Matlab mex files.

Comment: Can you try running `mex -setup` and update the question with the results of doing that?

Comment: It could be worth running `which mex` to make sure your path hasn't been tampered with.